# How can I use Jackson to convert a javafx.scene.paint.Color to and from JSON

Tags: jackson, javafx-8

I am trying to find an example, but to no avail of how to reconstitute the javafx.scene.paint.Color JSON back into a POJO.

When I create the JSON, the Color.RED is turned into this:

```
{
  "annotationText" : "5/5/2015 12:18 PM",
  "pageNumber" : 0,
  "textColor" : {
  "red" : 1.0,
  "green" : 0.0,
  "blue" : 0.0,
  "opacity" : 1.0,
  "opaque" : true,
  "brightness" : 1.0,
  "hue" : 0.0,
  "saturation" : 1.0
  },
"fillColor" : null
}
```

I am not sure how to parse that back in so that the it puts Color.RED back into the textColor field on my POJO.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Have a look at [this blog](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization) on custom deserialization. You can just grab the double values `red`, `green`, `blue`, and `opacity`, and pass them to the [`Color` constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/paint/Color.html#Color-double-double-double-double-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comment above - I was able to make it work like so:

```
public class AnnotationDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<AnnotationDetail>{

    @Override
    public AnnotationDetail deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) 
      throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        AnnotationDetail detail = new AnnotationDetail();

        JsonNode node = jp.getCodec().readTree(jp);

        detail.setAnnotationText(node.get("annotationText").asText());
        detail.setPageNumber((Integer) ((IntNode) node.get("pageNumber")).numberValue());

        JsonNode textColorNode = node.get("textColor");
        double red =(Double) ((DoubleNode) textColorNode.get("red")).numberValue();
        double green = (Double) ((DoubleNode) textColorNode.get("green")).numberValue();
        double blue = (Double) ((DoubleNode) textColorNode.get("blue")).numberValue();
        double opacity = (Double) ((DoubleNode) textColorNode.get("opacity")).numberValue();

        detail.setTextColor(new Color(red, green, blue, opacity));
        return detail;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To deserialize a pure JavaFX Color object, you can use this:

```
public class ColorDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Color> {

    @Override
    public Color deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
        JsonNode node = p.getCodec().readTree(p);
        double red = node.get("red").doubleValue();
        double green = node.get("green").doubleValue();
        double blue = node.get("blue").doubleValue();
        double opacity = node.get("opacity").doubleValue();

        return new Color(red, green, blue, opacity);
    }

}
```

And you have to register the deserializer in your module:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
module.addDeserializer(Color.class, new ColorDeserializer());
mapper.registerModule(module);

Color readValue = mapper.readValue(json, Color.class);
```